# Find different file in directory

Tags: diff, uniq

I try find one file that is different on folder.
I have 4 files i.e. file1, file2, file3 and file4. File from 1 to 3 have text "not uniq", file 4 is empty. How can i find this different file? I tried with diff, but diff works with 2 files.

Comment: `md5sum * | grep $(md5sum * | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | grep " 1 " | awk '{print $2}' | head -1) | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: @tetech thanks :) i find simplest solution, i mean 'md5sum * | sort -r | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: Cool, sure, it was not a real "answer" just to get you started with ideas.